# Testing a generator function has weird behavior

Tags: python, generator, pytest, yield

I have found a weird behavior that it is related to testing generator functions. I guess that there is a reason behind it, but I don't undestand what. This is my code:

```py
class Foo:
    def foo_function(self):
        return range(10)

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = Foo()

    def baz(self):
        for i in self.client.foo_function():
            yield i
```

And this is my test:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.test import TestCase

from my_app.my_module.client import Client


class ClientTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch('my_app.my_module.client.Foo')
    def test_baz(self, foo):
        client = Client('')
        client.baz()

        foo().foo_function.assert_called_once()
```

When I run this test, I get an `AssertionError`:

```sh
AssertionError: Expected 'foo_function' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

which could be just my fault, but once I try to debug with `pdb` I see the strange behavior. If I put the trace inside `foo_function`, I realized that it never gets inside it. So putting the trace right before calling it and stepping in, gives me a `GeneratorExit` and leaves:

```sh
[28] > /app/my_app/my_module/tests/test_client.py(14)test_baz()
-> client.baz()
   6 frames hidden (try 'help hidden_frames')
(Pdb++) step
--Call--
[29] > /app/my_app/my_module/client.py(11)foo_function()
-> def foo_function(self):
   6 frames hidden (try 'help hidden_frames')
(Pdb++) next
GeneratorExit
[29] > /app/my_app/my_module/client.py(11)foo_function()
-> def foo_function(self):
   6 frames hidden (try 'help hidden_frames')
(Pdb++)
```

I am sure it is not related to the mock either, because I have been making changes to try to understand what is going on, but I still can't find any reason. Does anybody have any idea what this is happening? And if so, how can I test a function like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `client.baz()` creates a generator. Generators do not execute any code until you start iterating over them.

Change `client.baz()` to `next(client.baz())` and your test will pass.

Comment: Right! My problem was understanding that: `Generators do not execute any code until you start iterating over them`. Thanks!